# Flex LineSeries interpolateValues as ZERO?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, interpolation

In a LineChart in Flex you can set a LineSeries to `interpolateValues="true"` what this does is connect missing values so you do not have gaps in your line. But what I would like is for it to insert 0's for the missing fields instead of drawing a direct line to fill the gap.

Is there a way to set it to do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: the only way to truly do this, is outside of FLEX, in your backend function that creates the data. you will have to "fabricate" the 0 values in your database function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can, interpolate is a way of guessing what your data point might have been. I think a quick function on your DataProvider could fill in the gaps with 0s though, and then you wouldn't have to mess with interpolation.